# i use the zeppelin with JDBCRealm ,but when i finished the configuration and started it, there shows 503 on the browser

Tags: mysql, apache-zeppelin, shiro

i started on a linux VM ware,and here comes the configuration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgKMc.png)

before i pasted it in the shiro.ini，the zeppelin can be visited by anonymous user(the default user), but after i copy shiro.ini.template to shiro.ini and paste the configuration under the line [main] and restart the zeppelin with zeppelin-daemon.sh ,then i connect to localhost:8080, the 503 error shows on the browser.

what can i do ? I want to use mysqlDatasource with JDBCRealm to authenticate users who use the zeppelin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When asking a question, it's best NOT to screenshot of code, use a code block directly.  It's also important to share what you have tried and any related error messages from log files.  Take a look at this post for more info on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Shiro will write the cause of the problem to the log file you have configured. If you haven't configured any, please see the zeppelin log file. Kindly post any output related to Shiro here.